# psycopg2 executemany ERROR: table tuple index out of range

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, execute

I am trying to insert data from a JSON file into a Postgres database, but I keep getting this error "table tuple index out of range".

I've been on this for a day and I can find my error. I would very much appreciate your help. Here is my code. I am using *executemany* and inserting 2 rows in the database

```
def bulkInsert(records, db_name, db_user, db_pass, db_endpoint):
try:
    connection = connect(db_name, db_user, db_pass, db_endpoint)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO raw.IncidentesViales (latitud, folio,
                                                            geopoint, hora_creacion,
                                                            delegacion_inicio, dia_semana,
                                                            fecha_creacion, ano,
                                                            tipo_entrada, codigo_cierre,
                                                            hora_cierre, incidente_c4, 
                                                            mes, delegacion_cierre, 
                                                            fecha_cierre, mesdecierre, 
                                                            longitud, clas_con_f_alarma) 
                           VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) """

    # executemany() to insert multiple rows rows
    result = cursor.executemany(sql_insert_query, records)
    connection.commit()
    print(cursor.rowcount, "***** Record inserted successfully into table *****")

except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
    print("***** Failed inserting record into table {} *****".format(error))

finally:
    # closing database connection.
    if (connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("***** PostgreSQL connection is closed *****")
```

I am using an intermediate function to get the fields I need from the JSON file and convert them into a list:

```
def records_rows(record):
l = [json.dumps(record['fields'][campo]) for campo in record['fields'].keys()]
return l
```

I get the *records* that I want to insert, those look like this (2 records):

[['19.31469',
  '"C4/131231/03346"',
  '[19.31469, -99.07113]',
  '"22:44:53"',
  '"IZTAPALAPA"',
  '"Martes"',
  '"31/12/2013"',
  '"2014"',
  '"LLAMADA DEL 066"',
  '"(I) El incidente reportado es afirmativo y se a\u00f1ade informaci\u00f3n adicional al evento"',
  '"02:11:35"',
  '"accidente-choque sin lesionados"',
  '"1"',
  '"IZTAPALAPA"',
  '"01/01/2014"',
  '"Enero"',
  '-99.07113',
  '"EMERGENCIA"'],
 ['19.36336',
  '"C4/140101/04189"',
  '[19.36336, -99.19104]',
  '"21:45:43"',
  '"ALVARO OBREGON"',
  '"Mi\u00e9rcoles"',
  '"01/01/2014"',
  '"2014"',
  '"LLAMADA DEL 066"',
  '"(A) La unidad de atenci\u00f3n a emergencias fue despachada, lleg\u00f3 al lugar de los hechos y confirm\u00f3 la emergencia reportada"',
  '"23:55:59"',
  '"accidente-choque con lesionados"',
  '"1"',
  '"ALVARO OBREGON"',
  '"01/01/2014"',
  '"Enero"',
  '-99.19104',
  '"URGENCIAS MEDICAS"']]

And I am calling the function like this:

```
bulkInsert([records_rows(record) for record in records], db_name, db_user_name, db_user_password, db_host)
```

BUT I keep getting the **ERROR: list index out of range**

Is it because I am using a list instead of a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just counted the number of commas, and your `sql_insert_query` has 18 columns whereas the two lists of values in `cursor.executemany()` have 17 each. Have you looked into that?

Edit1: Wait, it is even more trivial. You are missing commas once in each list of values. Search `'11' '12'`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a comma issue. However, I am trying to insert the values of a JSON file into a table. I updated my question.